# Calculating surface temperature from solar radiation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, temperature, material-science, thermal-radiation

Knowing how much solar radiation an object is exposed to, how can we calculate the temperature on the surface of the object? Example: If we have $800 \frac{W}{m^{2}}$ incoming solar energy onto a block of concrete, after 1h what will be its temperature?

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: This does not sound like homework, as it is a bit of an impossible assignment. Unless of course the teacher wanted to elicit relevant questions like what the ambient temperature was etc etc.

Comment: It's not home work, It is a question that can help with my master dissertation and I read a lot of papers but I could not find what I need. A friend of mine suggested asking here but I guess its a relay complex topic. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's what you need: first, the radiation absorption coefficient for concrete. this represents the fraction of incident radiation (at the wavelengths of interest) which is absorbed (versus that which is reflected). then you need the emission coefficient, which tells you how much the concrete block re-radiates that heat as it gets warm. Note that the absorption and emission coefficients are not necessarily the same.

Then you need the total mass and the illuminated area of the concrete block and the specific heat capacity of concrete; this tells you how much heat input is required to raise the temperature of the concrete by one degree. then you need the thermal conductivity of the concrete, which tells you how easily a given volume of it shares its heat with other volumes adjacent to it.

Then you need to know the amount of heat lost to the soil surrounding it; this requires knowledge of the surface area in contact with the soil, the soil temperature, and the thermal conductivity coefficient of the soil/concrete interface.

Then you set up a heat balance equation, where the incoming heat energy rate is set equal to the buildup of heat inside the concrete plus the heat losses due to conduction into the soil and radiation away from the block's surface, and solve.

if you want the time-dependence of the temperature, you'll have to include the rate of heat conduction from the heated surface to the interior of the block. If not, then you can assume the steady-state condition for the heat balance.

This furnishes an estimate only, as it ignores convective losses due to air motion at the heated surface of the block.

Answer (score 1):

If your piece of concrete was floating in the space you could use Stephan's law $W=\sigma T^4$  where $\sigma=5.670~373(21) \cdot 10^{-8}~\rm W m^{-2}K^{-1}$, but here on Earth as the other answer explained there are other factors to consider, which makes it very difficult to estimate the temperature accurately. You need to consider loss of heat due to conduction, convection and re-radiation.